# PMT function in PHP

Tags: php, html

I have been trying to implement the PMT function into PHP to use as a loan calculator.

The PHP code is not working and I'm not too sure why, please note I am a complete beginner.

PHP(Get.php):

```
<?php
    $loan = $_POST["loanamount"];
    $interest = $_POST["interest"];
    $months = $_POST["months"];

   function pmt($interest, $months, $loan) {
       $months = $months;
       $interest = $interest / 1200;
       $amount = $interest * -$loan * pow((1 + $interest), $months) / (1 - pow((1 + $interest), $months));
       return number_format($amount, 2);
    }

    echo "Your payment will be &pound;" . round($amount,2) . " a month, for " . $months . " months";

?>
```

HTML:

```
<form action="get.php" method="post">

    Loan Amount: <input type="text" min="1" name="loanamount"><br />
    Intrest: <input type="text" min="1" name="interest"><br />
    Months: <input type="text" min="1" name="months"><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    Monthly repayment: 


</form>
```

Thanking you in advance.

Comment: Because you're never actually *calling* the `pmt()` function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You created the function pmt but you never call it anywhere.

To get this to work you actually need to call the pmt function.

So something like this

```
<?php
    $loan = $_POST["loanamount"];
    $interest = $_POST["interest"];
    $months = $_POST["months"];

   function pmt($interest, $months, $loan) {
       $months = $months;
       $interest = $interest / 1200;
       $amount = $interest * -$loan * pow((1 + $interest), $months) / (1 - pow((1 + $interest), $months));
       return number_format($amount, 2);
    }

    $amount = pmt($interest, $months, $loan);
    echo "Your payment will be &pound;" . round($amount,2) . " a month, for " . $months . " months";

?>
```

Comment: I am not a PHP expert but that `$months = $months;` looks a bit useless.

Answer (score 2):

You're not calling your `pmt()` function.  Add the following line before your echo statement:

```
$amount = pmt($interest, $months, $loan);
```